# run celery task by clicking a button in template (html page) django

Tags: django, task, celery

I have some tasks in my application and I whoud that user could run the celery task by click  button django (after enter some args).

how can I do this.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You should write custom view which handles some data (args) and run your task (probably by apply_async/delay method).

Comment: I need that a task started if I click a button "run name_task". how to call task from  template (user interface)?

Comment: As I said - write custom view which will be executed after user clicks on that button. Simple scenario:
1. User clicked at "run make_order" button
2. Redirect him to /tasks/run/make_order/
3. In view add given task to queue
4. Redirect user to previous page with message that task has been scheduled.